# ModuleNotFound Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

In my Macs Terminal I'm not able to use Python packages as I get a ModuleNotFound error. This is not the case in VS code, as I tried all kinds of things, including a venv based from a tutorial, and it seemed to work.

When I run `pip install requests` I get the following:

> - Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>   (2.25.1)
> - Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>   (from requests) (4.0.0)
> - Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>   (from requests) (1.26.5)
> - Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>   (from requests) (2.10)
> - Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
>   (from requests) (2020.12.5)

When I run `python --version` I get Python 3.9.5

I've spend hours now trying to get this "environment" up and correctly running, but with not much success.

Comment: Hi, @Nuxurious Mind sharing what exactly do you write in your terminal window?

Comment: Hi @bot-coder101, what I do is I go into Terminal, type in Python which then seems to make the Terminal switch to python, and then I simply type in "import requests" or "import paperclip" -- both which I have installed via Pip and can run in VS code - and then get an error. When I run files via changing directory, and running python randomfile.py with a 3rd party module in it, I also get the error. Not when I run directly in VS code.

Comment: Did you try writing a script in a text editor like nano/vim through terminal and then running the script like python3 file.py? Is it working or it gives the same error?

Comment: Hi @9769953, the output I got from that command:
['', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/Bas/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

Comment: @bot-coder101 I'm not familiar with those text editors and just started coding, but to add, in IDLE the modules also work with zero problem.

Comment: @9769953 strange. I ran the `which python` command in both bash terminals and for both I got `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: @9769953 my bad. I ran it through the Terminal app and through VS Code menu bar > Terminal > New terminal. I'm not sure how to do it otherwise?

Comment: Yes. In VS code, in a .py file, if I use `import requests` or `import pyperclip` it doesn't give an error - and pyperclip works. In Terminal, it does.

Comment: It has a shell promo ($) and the interactive shell is zsh. It returns the `/usr/local/bin/python` and when I press enter on that, it starts Python. However, I just ran `import requests` which returned a ModuleNotFoundError. When I just run a .py file with import requests through a Run Python file in Terminal prompt by VS code, it works fine.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep that in mind. In the shell it displays, and the script just returned `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`. I tried to use that as the path in Terminal through some code, today, but perhaps that did not succeed.

Comment: Which pip in zsh terminal returned `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip
`

Comment: When I ran that path, import requests worked! Now I need to try and make it default, I suppose?

Comment: `python3` also worked!

Comment: @9769953 I'm still getting some errors. For example, I just switched to my folder where Python scripts are contained (those which work in VS code) and tried to run one including `import requests` and a `print("Hello world")` but it returned a ModuleNotFoundError. 

Edit: this is in zsh, changing directory to python folder, then running `python file.py`

Comment: this is in zsh, changing directory to python folder, then running `python file.py`

Comment: Nevermind it's late here. Haha my bad. Ran `python3 file.py` and it worked fine. Thank you for the help! I appreciate it!

Comment: @9769953 Many thanks again btw for writing out a very detailed answer! I was able to create an alias for python that goes to python3 which now also works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple Python versions installed. One possibly from the official Python website, and one through Homebrew (I'm guessing a bit). These interfere somewhat.

Here's the thing though: the "official" one didn't not install the standard `python` alias. It only installed the more explicit `python3` command. Oddly (and confusingly) enough, it did install `pip`, probably alongside `pip3`.

When you type `python`, the shell will find the one installed by Homebrew; the other one doesn't not exist. When you explicitly type `python3`, you'll get the correct one. It looks like your `PATH` environment variable is set up to have the "official" installation come first, and then the Homebrew one.

So, best and easiest is to simply use `python3` explicitly.

You could attempt to uninstall the Homebrew one in `/usr/local/` if you want to and don't think you need it.

You could also tinker inside the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin` and make an alias for `python`, but I wouldn't recommend it, unless you become more familiar with the shell, Python installations and your system. And after all, it's only one character more to type currently.

Comment: do you get the same thing for `python --version` and `python3 --version`? How about `pip --version`, `python -m pip --version` and `python3 -m pip --version`