# python error : from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

This is my first question in Stack Overflow. And yes, I am quite of a beginner in coding. I have developed a web app with Django / Wagtail. I wanted to work from home and work. I bought a mac mini M2. At my other computer, everything works fine. No issues on the application running on local mode. However, when I installed my new computer with all packages, I came across the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcmini/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/GitHub/Ellipsis-Web/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I have these versions:
pyenv versions
system

- 3.9.2 (set by /Users/marcmini/.pyenv/version)
  3.10.10
  3.11.2

And the Django version 4.1.7 ( I run inside my project PIP LIST and all packages appear - I won't list all because I suppose that's not a problem )

My files are in iCloud, so I am not sure if it is a path issue.
marcmini@Mac-mini-de-Marc ellipsis-web % pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.5.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from django) (3.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from django) (0.4.3)

I have checked this solution but it doesn't work [the one that gets 288 or so votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591971/how-can-i-fix-the-zsh-command-not-found-python-error-macos-monterey-12-3)

Many thanks in advance !!!!

To run my code remotely

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came to the right answer here: [ModuleNotFound Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67779792/modulenotfound-python?rq=1)

Since I decided to install versions of Python for various reasons, I had to explicitly run in my terminal the following command:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```